# Integrating Firebase SDK inside an internal SDK

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I work on a iOS SDK team. We provide internal SDKs to the teams working in our organization. I am trying to add `FirebaseSDK` in one of our SDKs and I realized how different `FirebaseSDK` and its initialization process is.

The first issue I am facing is the `plist` file that `FirebaseSDK` requires in order to get initialized. It requires a `bundleId`, so it has to be in one of the clients applications that uses our SDK.

The issue that follows is that `FirebaseSDK` can't be initialized without a valid `plist` file. Now that the `plist` file is in the client application, we have to initialize `FirebaseSDK` over there as well.

Long story short, I don't see a good way of adding `FirebaseSDK` into our internal SDK. That implies FirebaseSDK is meant to be used directly by clients and it can't be added to another SDK.

I tried accessing `plist` file from the clients app into the SDK and initialize FirebaseSDK into my SDK, but it didn't work. It looks like the initialization has to happen in app delegate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no plist requirement. The plist is just an option that most people find convenient.

You can initialize Firebase by passing all the required values via an [FirebaseOptions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasecore/api/reference/Classes/FirebaseOptions) object when calling [FirebaseApp.configure()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasecore/api/reference/Classes/FirebaseApp#/c:objc(cs)FIRApp(cm)configureWithOptions:). You can get the options values from the plist that you get from the Firebase console.

Comment: This is true except for FirebaseAnalytics which does require a plist file - https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/230